# Orthogonal Vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ where $n>3$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

While studying orthogonality and orthonormal bases, I found it hard to conceptualize orthogonal vectors in a Vector Space over $\Bbb R^n$ with $n>3$. In $\Bbb R^3$, we get the set of orthogonal vectors similar to the x,y,z axes.

In $\Bbb R^3$, vectors are orthogonal to planes, computed by looking at the vector's projection onto a plane(s). However, in $\Bbb R^4$, we are no longer looking at the projection onto a plane but rather the projection onto a vector space in $\Bbb R^3$?

So to find orthongonal vectors you would need to find the projection onto the span of three vectors in $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: What exactly does *find orthogonal vectors* mean?

Comment: An easy criterion for orthogonality comes from the "dot product".

Comment: It's hard to picture anything in $\mathbb R^n$ with $n>3$

Comment: The standard way to picture things in ${\bf R}^n$ for $n>3$ is to first picture them in ${\bf R}^{\infty}$ and then cut the picture down to dimension $n$.

Comment: @Azif00 finding an orthonormal basis consisting of unit vectors orthogonal to one another.

Comment: @RaoulDuke So, in $\mathbb R^4$, take $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Rule is that the sum of dimensions of orthogonal subspaces is the dimension of the ambient space. 
So since in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you have 3 dimensions, the orthogonal space of a vector (which is a 1 dimensional object) is a plane, because 3-1 = 2 and the plane is 2 dimensional  . So any object inside the plane orthogonal to that vector is orthogonal to the vector. Vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be orthogonal to other vectors, to lines, and ultimately to planes.

(Example: if I consider the vector $a = (0,0,1)$ his orthogonal plane is $\pi = \{z = 0\}$ which consists of the vectors $(x,y,0)$ with random $x$ and $y$. Hence the plane $\pi$ is orthogonal to $a$, and any vector inside $\pi$ is also orthogonal to $a$.)

Hence in $\mathbb{R}^4$, since you have 4 dimensions, the space orthogonal to a vector is a 3 dimensional space. (Ex:vector $(0,0,0,1)$ and space $(x,y,z,0)$ are orthogonal.

Yes, in $\mathbb{R}^4$ to find a vector orthogonal to a 3 dimensional space, you have to see if the projection of that vector on the span of 3 vectors generating your space is 0.